# Deploy Office 2007 add-in

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, ms-office

I have created a PowerPoint addin using the steps from this article:
[Using RibbonX from Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163410.aspx)

The plugin works fine when I start the project using F5 in Visual Studio 2005. But if I try to use the installer created by the setup project that is automatically added to the solution, the plug-in won't show when I run powerpnt.exe

Is there something I missed? Do I need to make some modifications to the installer?

Comment: I can definately say "Yes" to that question, but I'm not at my workstation atm, so I can't elaborate further. I did however find what I needed using the power of Google.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also enabled the plugin in Powerpoint -> Options -> Add-ins on the machines where you installed the Add-in?